# Google Maps - Make route line follow streets when map zoomed in

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm getting the same issue as described in following SO questions:

(The route lines is not following the streets when I zoom in)

[MapKit - Make route line follow streets when map zoomed in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13013873/mapkit-make-route-line-follow-streets-when-map-zoomed-in?rq=1)

and

[Route drawing on Google Maps for iOS not following the street lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22526577/route-drawing-on-google-maps-for-ios-not-following-the-street-lines)

But seems there are no any answer which solved mentioned issue.

I'm adding to points to the my GMSMapView map by following function:

```
-(void) addPointToMap:(CLLocationCoordinate2D) coordinate
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(
                                                                 coordinate.latitude,
                                                                 coordinate.longitude);
    GMSMarker *marker = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:position];
    marker.map = mapView_;
    [waypoints_ addObject:marker];
    NSString *positionString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%f,%f",
                                coordinate.latitude,coordinate.longitude];
    [waypointStrings_ addObject:positionString];
    if([waypoints_ count]>1){
        NSString *sensor = @"false";
        NSArray *parameters = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sensor, waypointStrings_,
                               nil];
        NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"sensor", @"waypoints", nil];
        NSDictionary *query = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:parameters
                                                          forKeys:keys];
        MDDirectionService *mds=[[MDDirectionService alloc] init];
        SEL selector = @selector(addDirections:);
        [mds setDirectionsQuery:query
                   withSelector:selector
                   withDelegate:self];
    }

}
```

and here are setDirectionsQuery function:

```
static NSString *kMDDirectionsURL = @"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?";

- (void)setDirectionsQuery:(NSDictionary *)query withSelector:(SEL)selector
              withDelegate:(id)delegate{
  NSArray *waypoints = [query objectForKey:@"waypoints"];
  NSString *origin = [waypoints objectAtIndex:0];
  int waypointCount = [waypoints count];
  int destinationPos = waypointCount -1;
  NSString *destination = [waypoints objectAtIndex:destinationPos];
  NSString *sensor = [query objectForKey:@"sensor"];
  NSMutableString *url =
  [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@&origin=%@&destination=%@&sensor=%@",
   kMDDirectionsURL,origin,destination, sensor];
  if(waypointCount>2) {
    [url appendString:@"&waypoints=optimize:true"];
    int wpCount = waypointCount-2;
    for(int i=1;i<wpCount;i++){
      [url appendString: @"|"];
      [url appendString:[waypoints objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
  }
    url = [url
           stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    _directionsURL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
  [self retrieveDirections:selector withDelegate:delegate];
}
```

Note: I have followed this Google tutorial and modified it a little bit:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AdV7bCWuDYg

Thanks in advance, any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I have found solution, Thanks to the  WWJD's last edit in his question!

[Route drawing on Google Maps for iOS not following the street lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22526577/route-drawing-on-google-maps-for-ios-not-following-the-street-lines?noredirect=1#comment38248419_22526577)

From the answer:

What I basically did before was that I was getting and working only with the information I'm receiving in the routes while if you check the JSON file you're receiving from Google Directions API, you'll see that you receive much more information in the  and the . This is the information we need to produce the proper results and the right polyline.